# qmake cannot find include files

Tags: qt, qmake

I'm using QtCreator with qmake and have set up my .pro file:

```
DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
CONFIG += staticlib

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/eigen3
INCLUDEPATH += /opt/userlibs
INCLUDEPATH += /opt/QcustomPlot/qcustomplot
INCLUDEPATH += /carbonics/owncloudsync/programs/C++/cmos_modeling_tests
INCLUDEPATH += /carbonics/owncloudsync/programs/C++/libraries/plotting/smithchart
INCLUDEPATH += /carbonics/owncloudsync/programs/C++/libraries/utilities
INCLUDEPATH += /opt/pagmo/include

PRECOMPILED_HEADER += /opt/userlibs/*
PRECOMPILED_HEADER += /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/*
PRECOMPILED_HEADER += /opt/QcustomPlot/qcustomplot/*


SOURCES += \
#    ../libraries/plotting/smithchart/colorlineedit.cpp \
#    ../libraries/plotting/smithchart/plotcurve.cpp \
#    ../libraries/plotting/smithchart/plotrectactions.cpp \
#    ../libraries/plotting/smithchart/plotsmithactions.cpp \
    ../libraries/plotting/smithchart/autolineedit.cpp \
#    ../libraries/plotting/smithchart/directoryselector.cpp \
    ../libraries/utilities/fileselector.cpp \
    ../libraries/utilities/formatnum.cpp \
    ../libraries/utilities/getfilenames_unbiased.cpp \
    ../libraries/utilities/getfilenames_vgs_vds.cpp \
#    ../libraries/utilities/getspar.cpp \
    ../libraries/utilities/linearregression.cpp \
    ../libraries/utilities/readallSpar.cpp \
    ../libraries/utilities/readsparameters.cpp \
    ../libraries/utilities/readwritedefault.cpp \
    ../libraries/utilities/sparfilenames.cpp \
    ../libraries/utilities/utilities.cpp \
    ../libraries/utilities/writespar.cpp \
    /opt/QcustomPlot/qcustomplot/qcustomplot.cpp \
    /carbonics/owncloudsync/programs/C++/cmos_modeling_tests/optimizer_test.cpp \
    /carbonics/owncloudsync/programs/C++/cmos_modeling_tests/readsparameters_test.cpp \
    cmosmodel1.cpp \
    getmodelelements.cpp \
    main.cpp \
    cmosmodelingmainwindow.cpp \
    modelcircuitelements.cpp \
    optimizer_test.cpp \
    problemcmosactivebias.cpp

HEADERS += \
#    ../libraries/plotting/smithchart/colorlineedit.h \
#    ../libraries/plotting/smithchart/plotcurve.h \
#    ../libraries/plotting/smithchart/plotrectactions.h \
#    ../libraries/plotting/smithchart/plotsetup.h \
#    ../libraries/plotting/smithchart/plotsmithactions.h \
    ../libraries/plotting/smithchart/autolineedit.h \
#    ../libraries/plotting/smithchart/directoryselector.h \
    ../libraries/utilities/fileselector.h \
    ../libraries/utilities/formatnum.h \
    ../libraries/utilities/getfilenames_vgs_vds.h \
    ../libraries/utilities/getfilenames_unbiased.h \
#    ../libraries/utilities/getspar.h \
    ../libraries/utilities/linearregression.h \
    ../libraries/utilities/pagmosetup.h \
    ../libraries/utilities/readallSpar.h \
    ../libraries/utilities/readsparameters.h \
    ../libraries/utilities/readwritedefault.h \
    ../libraries/utilities/sparfilenames.h \
    ../libraries/utilities/utilities.h \
    ../libraries/utilities/writespar.h \
    ../libraries/utilities/qtsetup.h \
    \
    /opt/QcustomPlot/qcustomplot/qcustomplot.h \
    /carbonics/owncloudsync/programs/C++/cmos_modeling_tests/optimizer_test.h \
    /carbonics/owncloudsync/programs/C++/cmos_modeling_tests/readsparameters_test.h \
    cmosmodel1.h \
    cmosmodelingmainwindow.h \
    getmodelelements.h \
    modelcircuitelements.h \
    modeldatatypes.h \
    optimizer_test.h \
    problemcmosactivebias.h

FORMS += \
    ../libraries/plotting/smithchart/plotsmithdialog.ui \
    ../libraries/plotting/smithchart/plotxydialog.ui \
    CMOSmodlingmainwindow.ui

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../opt/pagmo/lib/release/ -lpagmo
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../opt/pagmo/lib/debug/ -lpagmo
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../opt/pagmo/lib/ -lpagmo

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../opt/pagmo/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../opt/pagmo/include
```

QtCreator can find the files optimizer_test.cpp, optimizer_test.h, readsparameters_test.cpp, and readsparameters_test.h just fine
However, when I invoke qmake from QtCreator, it cannot find the above *.h files.
I've carefully checked that these files are in the specified directories, but qmake keeps throwing the errors that it cannot find these files. qmake finds all the other include files just fine. I can't for the life of me understand why qmake is failing - a real mystery. I've tried removing the build directories as well as cleaning the project.
I've tried uncommenting the DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000
line but it did not help.
Thanks,
Phil

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! I found my stupid mistake!
I had added the "optimizer_test.h" and "optimizer_test.cpp" twice in two different directories. Previously, I had moved the above files from the root sources directory to /carbonics/owncloudsync/programs/C++/cmos_modeling_tests.
Of course, QtCreator tried to find them in the original sources directory to no avail and hence my error messages!
Sorry again to waste your time and thanks!
Phil